# Multiply std::vector<cv::Point3f> by a cv::Mat?

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

as above, I have a std::vector of cv::Point3f. I have a transformation matrix. I need to multiply the vector by the inverse of the Mat.

My Mat: (`T` is the resulting transformation)

```
cv::Mat R(3,3,rvec.type());
cv::Rodrigues(rvec, R); // R is 3x3
cv::Mat T(4, 4, R.type()); // T is 4x4
T(cv::Range(0, 3), cv::Range(0, 3)) = R * 1; // copies R into T
T(cv::Range(0, 3), cv::Range(3, 4)) = tvec * 1; // copies tvec into T
float *p = T.ptr<float>(3);
p[0] = p[1] = p[2] = 0; p[3] = 1;
```

my vector:

`std::vector<cv::Point3f> objectPoints;`

I have tried:

```
cv::Mat V = T.inv() * cv::Mat(objectPoints, false) 
V.copyTo(cv::Mat(objectPoints, false));
```

(Assertion failed, type error)

```
for (int i = 0; i < objectPoints.size(); i++)
{
    cv::Mat dst = cv::Mat(objectPoints[i], false);  
    dst = -T*dst; //USE MATRIX ALGEBRA 
//  cv::Point3f tmp3 = cv::Point3f(dst(0, 0), dst(1, 0), dst(2, 0));

}
```

(Assertion failed)

```
    std::vector<cv::Point3f> p3d;
perspectiveTransform(objectPoints, p3d, -T);
```

(runs, but the values are very incorrect)

`cv::transform(objectPoints, p3d, -T);`

(Assertion error)

What is the correct way (if there is a way!) to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: So you want to multiply `std::vector<cv::Point3f>` with an inverse of `cv::Mat` and do you want result to be a Mat or it doesn't matter?

Comment: Ideally, the result would be a new std::vector<point3f>. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Ideally, `cv::Mat V = T.inv() * cv::Mat(objectPoints, false) 
V.copyTo(cv::Mat(objectPoints, false));` should work. Can you add the type of Mat?

Comment: It uses the same type as `rvec`, which i initialize as: `cv::Mat rvec(3, 1, cv::DataType<float>::type);`

Comment: I think the problem is you are trying to multiply a 4*4 matrix with a n*3 (`cv::Point3f` converted to `Mat`) which will not work

Comment: hmmm ok. How can i get around this? can I just use `rvec` and `tvec` for this? Or should I add another `0` column to the Mat?

Comment: I see that you are making the matrix homogeneous by adding 1's at the bottom. If the `std::vector` isn't too big, why don't you multiply element-wise **without** homogeneous coordinates?

Comment: So i would make it `cv::Mat T(3, 4, R.type());`? can you explain 'element wise' please? t

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Rick M. pointed out, you're trying to multiply a 4x4 matrix with a length-3 point. To perform a transformation with just one matrix multiplication (i.e. with the 4x4 combined R-T matrix), you first have to represent the point in homogeneous coordinates, which essentially just involves tacking on a 1 as the 4th element of your point; after the transformation, you divide the new point by the 4th element to maintain its value as a 1. [Here's](http://inside.mines.edu/~whoff/courses/EENG512/lectures/04-3Dto3DTransforms.pdf) a nice source on 3D-3D transformations, with homogeneous coordinates discussed on slide 14.

Since OpenCV doesn't have a Point4f class, you'll have to add this 1 when you're creating the Mat form of the point. This is untested but might work:

```
std::vector<cv::Point3f> dstPoint;
for (int i = 0; i < objectPoints.size(); i++) {
    // Convert Point3f to 4x1 Mat (in homogeneous coordinates, with 1 as 4th element)
    cv::Point3f pt = objectPoints[i];
    cv::Mat ptMat = (cv::Mat_<float>(4,1) << pt.x, pt.y, pt.z, 1);

    // Perform matrix multiplication and store as Mat_ for easy element access
    cv::Mat_<float> dstMat(T.inv() * ptMat); 

    // Divide first three resulting elements by the 4th (homogenizing 
    // the point) and store as Point3f
    float scale = dstMat(0,3);
    cv::Point3f dst(dstMat(0,0)/scale, dstMat(0,1)/scale, dstMat(0,2)/scale);
    dstPoints.push_back(dst)
}
```

Would test, but I'm at work and don't have OpenCV on this computer.

**UPDATE:**

When copying to T, try this instead:

```
cv::Mat T(4, 4, cv::DataType<float>::type);
cv::Mat rot   = T(cv::Range(0, 3), cv::Range(0, 3));
cv::Mat trans = T(cv::Range(0, 3), cv::Range(3, 4));
R.copyTo(rot);
tvec.copyTo(trans);
```

Comment: Thank you! This gives me a crash at `cv::Mat_<float> dstMat(T.inv() * ptMat);`, with:  


`OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (type == _src2.type() && (type == CV_32F || type
== CV_64F)) in cv::solve, file D:\thirdParty\opencv_320\opencv-master\modules\co
re\src\lapack.cpp, line 1094`

Comment: Darn. Had a feeling that casting wouldn't work. What happens when you just do `cv::Mat dstMat = T.inv() * ptMat;` ? Does this line fail?

Comment: Looking more closely at the error, it seems to be an issue with types in the matrix multiplication. So I'd check the types of T and ptMat to ensure that they are the same and are either 32-bit or 64-bit floats.

Comment: ok! changing the `T` initialization to : `cv::Mat T(4, 4, cv::DataType<float>::type);` has it compiling, but the resulting values are: 
`-nan(ind) -nan(ind) -nan(ind)`

Comment: Yikes... Would you print out the matrix `T.inv()`? I have a feeling that the `T` is an ill-conditioned matrix... If `T.inv()` is defined, I'd print out the values you get for `scale` to ensure that they aren't zero.

Comment: hmmm, strange. `rvec` and `tvec` print what i would expect. `R` prints as expected, but `T` prints a zero Matrix.

Comment: If i undo the float initialization, I get T:   ` 0.001330603394833468, 0.9999951264159792, 0.00282429440665495, -3.5873389976501
85e-05;
 0.04408990169842637, -0.002880216454657183, 0.9990234156021557, -0.002968000196
168561;
 0, 0.0078125, 1.076858045122215e-65, 5.616881825382601e-85]

` ... but the Assertion error.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer by DCSmith, I have it working. I had to make this small change:

```
cv::Mat T(4, 4, cv::DataType<float>::type);
R.copyTo(T(cv::Rect(0, 0, 3, 3)));
tvec.copyTo(T(cv::Rect(3, 0, 1, 3)));
```

To make the entire function look like:

```
std::vector<cv::Point3f> p3d;

cv::Mat R(3,3, cv::DataType<float>::type);
cv::Rodrigues(rvec, R); // R is 3x3
cv::Mat T(4, 4, cv::DataType<float>::type);

R.copyTo(T(cv::Rect(0, 0, 3, 3)));
tvec.copyTo(T(cv::Rect(3, 0, 1, 3)));

float *p = T.ptr<float>(3);
p[0] = p[1] = p[2] = 0; p[3] = 1;


std::vector<cv::Point3f> dstPoint;
for (int i = 0; i < objectPoints.size(); i++) {
    cv::Point3f pt = objectPoints[i];
    cv::Mat ptMat = (cv::Mat_<float>(4, 1) << pt.x, pt.y, pt.z, 1);

    // Perform matrix multiplication and store as Mat_ for easy element access
    cv::Mat_<float> dstMat = T.inv() * ptMat;

    // Divide first three resulting elements by the 4th (homogenizing 
    // the point) and store as Point3f
    float scale = dstMat(0, 3);
    cv::Point3f dst(dstMat(0, 0) / scale, dstMat(0, 1) / scale, dstMat(0, 2) / scale);
    p3d.push_back(dst);
}
```

Thank you for your help!